# Implementing bodyWithBodies in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, skshapenode

I am using Apple's Sprite Kit to create a game, and currently I have drawn an `SKShapeNode` object that looks similar to the following:

[image]

My actual sprite has rounded edges, but for simplicity, I am trying to get everything working with this shape first. I am able to draw the sprite perfectly fine. However, I am having trouble creating a physics body to cover the sprite. I want the sprite to recognize collisions anywhere along its surface, so I want a physics body that covers only the dark gray area. Also, I want the sprite to respond to forces and impulses, so I need a volume-based physics body.

My first idea was to simply use the same `CGPathRef` that I used to create the image for the sprite, and pass it to the `bodyWithPolygonFromPath` method to create a corresponding physics body. I have come to find this will not work, as my shape is not convex.

So, now I am thinking I should be able to use `bodyWithBodies` to create a physics body shaped appropriately. I want to create three rectangular physics bodies (one to cover the left of the gray area, one to cover the top, and one to cover the right), and use those to create one physics body whose area covers the gray area of my sprite by using this:

```
    mySprite.physicsbody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithBodies:@[body1, body2, body3]];
```

However, the main problem I am having is correctly positioning the individual bodies that go into the array, which is passed to the `bodyWithBodies` method. By using the above method, I obviously have no way of controlling where these physics bodies are being placed in relation to each other. The result is all three physics bodies stacking on top of each other in the center of `mySprite`.

How exactly are you supposed to position the physics bodies in the array relative to each other before passing them to the `bodyWithBodies` method?

Comment: [bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/SKPhysicsBody/bodyWithRectangleOfSize:center:)

Comment: Ah, I searched for hours in the documentation. I can't believe I didn't see that. Works perfectly. Thank you very much.